# How to Get Water Filtered with Silver for a Student?

Tags: water, filter

Student so I am searching for a low budget product but can 100-200 e if necessary. 
I did not find any good products in AliExpress. 
Now, I am considering the product [here](https://www.amazon.de/Wasser-Ionisator-aQuator-basisches-Wasser-saures/dp/B00JR25L8S/ref=pd_sim_sbs_364_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=41gE7taNRaL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR157%2C160_&refRID=7JVYHJ8JN0N5W6NMRG2F) but it is rather expensive (400 euros)

[image]

I am not sure if there is any passive water-silver filter.
The search also returns the item [here](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B005ZI6OVQ?psc=1) but it does not seem to have any silver

[image]

---

How can you get Water Filtered with Silver for a student?

Comment: Masi, I've noticed quite a few of your past questions were also closed or deleted. Please see [what topics can I ask about here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) along with other topics in the help center to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Barrow filter is intended for installing in a computer liquid cooling system. As such it is off-topic here. It is not suitable for installing into a household water supply pipe.

The other device probably performs no useful function but it is meant to be placed in a perforated canister that you drop into a bottle of water and shake before drinking the water. It also is not suitable for installing in a household water supply pipe.

Comment: @Masi: see [What is on-topic](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Shopping questions](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2815). I would stop looking at these snake-oil fake products and go to a reputable plumbing supplies store nearby.

Comment: @Masi: I would search for *"plumbed-in water filter"* or "plumbed in reverse-osmosis". You might get useful answers here if you search here too and if necessary, ask a new question here describing the problem with your water supply that you want to correct or ameliorate.

Comment: @Masi: constantly mutating questions are no fun to answer, so I'm stepping away from this.